# Access my home files via web browser

Tags: software-rec

I am looking for a solution to access the files on my home computer using nothing but a browser.

- I do not want to have to download any client software (Java ok).
- I do not care about sharing or streaming media.
- Must be secure.
- Must be free.
- Must not use a third party site to store files.
- I have an SSH server setup so file access is possible with WinSCP.
- I can install another piece of software on the host if needed.
- Must run as a Windows Service!! If I have to log into Windows first then it's a FAIL.

Bonus

- Able to edit Word documents via browser interface (I can dream can't I?)

Comment: Maybe you want to check out [Microsoft SkyDrive](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_live/b/windowslive/archive/2010/06/07/office-is-now-live-on-skydrive.aspx).

Comment: @OliverSalzburg SkyDrive stores files on Microsoft servers, which breaks one of his requirements. This means Dropbox is out, too.

Comment: Technically dropbox does cloud stuff, but the content is only there if the content exists in a folder on his computer, delete the file on the computer, its deleted from the cloud. If he has concerns with putting stuff in the cloud though, then yes, Dropbox is out.

Comment: BTW, "security" relies as much on your ability to properly configure the solution as the solution itself.

Comment: Why not just use FTP? All major browsers support it.

Comment: are you away from your home computer? you can use teamviewer

Answer (score 2):

If you have `python3` installed, you can type this command:

```
C:\> python -m http.server
```

It will start a http file server on `port:8000`

Answer (score 1):

Use a HTTP Fileserver. A great one is [HFS](http://www.rejetto.com/hfs/).

This is what it looks like from a browser [image: visual directory listing]

[How to secure it.](http://www.rejetto.com/wiki/index.php?title=HFS:_Secure_your_server)

[How to run it as a service.](http://www.rejetto.com/forum/index.php?topic=4713.0)

Hope this helps.

Comment: This looks great.  I will give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a bit overkill but [ownCloud](http://owncloud.org/) could be a solution. It's similar to [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) but you run it on your own server.

Comment: ownCloud looks great but I cannot find any information on if it runs as a Windows Service or not.

Comment: It runs on top of your web-server (IIS I would guess in the Windows case). And I would assume that the web-server runs as a Windows Service.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to take a look at this [http file server](http://www.gleamtech.com/products/filevista/web-file-manager). You can set up your own file server for managing and sharing files through web browser. It's like DropBox but self-hosted so that you can keep all your confidential files on your own server. The web based UI looks and feels like Windows 7 Explorer. It offers features that are not possible with a FTP server such as zipping files, downloading multiple files and folders in single download etc. It's also easier to set up and administrate than a FTP server.